# Matlab: efficienting portion of code, random start

Tags: matlab

I have the following code that generates a matrix of 15 blocks that will then be used in a Montecarlo approach as multiple starting points. How can I get the same exact result in a smarter way?

assume that J=15*100 are the total simulation and paramNum the number of parameters

```
[10^-10*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-9*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-8*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-7*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-6*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-5*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) rand*10^-5*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-4*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) rand*10^-4*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-3*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-2*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-1*ones(paramNum,round(J/15)) 10^-abs(randn/2)*ones(paramNum,round(J/15))];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
v = 10.^[-10:-5 rand*10^-5 -4:-1 10^-abs(randn/2)];
repmat(repelem(v, 1, round(J/15)), paramNum) .* ... 
repmat(ones(paramNum,round(J/15)), numel(v))
```

Or mimic the repmat/repelem functionality with a for loop. The first is shorter, the later is more understandable.

By the way... it's less than 15 blocks...